# Windows10でエクスプローラーの検索ボックスの特定の検索履歴を消す方法

Tags: windows-10

Windwos10でエクスプローラー(フォルダー画面)の右上にあるファイルを検索する「検索」ボックスの検索履歴を消すやり方ついて質問です。

Windows7では検索履歴にカーソルをあわせてdelキーで個別に履歴の削除できましたが、調べてもWindows10では一括で消す方法しか出てきませんでした。
あと、検索履歴を無効化する方法も出ませんでした。

https://hayakute.kantan-sakusaku.com/windows/2019/1213185309/

---

1. エクスプローラーの検索ボックスの特定の検索履歴だけを消す方法
2. エクスプローラーの検索履歴を無効化する方法

を教えてください

よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 2):

1. エクスプローラーの検索ボックスの特定の検索履歴だけを消す方法
   こちらで大まかに解説されています。
   [エクスプローラの検索履歴を消去する](https://note.com/_thinkingbird/n/nfef33a77e9eb)
   ただし、レジストリを直接操作・Unicode(UTF-16)データがバイナリ表示・1つだけ消すには個々の番号エントリと`MRUListEx`の両方を整合性を保って操作する必要あり、となっているので手作業では非常に面倒ですし、対応しているツールは無さそうです。
   ・
   なお、上記記事ではレジストリのツリー位置情報末尾が微妙に切れていて完全では無いので、以下記事を参照。
   [How to Delete the Search History in Windows File Explorer](https://www.howtogeek.com/282281/how-to-delete-the-search-history-in-windows-file-explorer/)
   [エクスプローラーの検索履歴を削除](https://ameblo.jp/h-aigo/entry-12444089716.html)
   [エクスプローラーの検索履歴を削除する](http://nonsubject.arinco.org/2010/09/blog-post_20.html)
2. エクスプローラーの検索履歴を無効化する方法
   以下のいずれかで出来そうです。
   [Windows10 エクスプローラーの検索履歴を非表示にする手順](https://freepc.jp/post-30267)
   [Windows10でエクスプローラーの検索履歴を無効化する](http://jiyugaoka.biz/cs/windows10-disablesearchboxsuggestions/) / 同じ内容 [エクスプローラーの検索履歴を削除する](http://nonsubject.arinco.org/2010/09/blog-post_20.html)

---

以下はそうした機能は無いとのこと：
<s>要望そのままのものでは無いかもしれませんが、こんな記事があって「エクスプローラの検索履歴」も対象にあるので、もしかしたら個々の検索履歴を消す機能があるかもしれません。

[10年を超える定番クリーナー「CCleaner」を10倍使いこなす 第3回](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/special/656296.html)

試してみてください。</s>

Comment: CCleaner での履歴削除は「検索履歴」や「ファイル名を指定して実行」などの大分類ごとで、質問のような個別エントリを選択した削除はできません。

Comment: なるほど、残念ながら、ということですね。